# abstracting object key in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm attempting to create a search function, built something like this:

```
function Search(array, key, query, target){
    var search_string = new RegExp(query, "i");

    var filtered_list = $.grep(array, function (value, index) {
        return (value.key.search(search_string) !=-1);
    });
    $(target).empty(); 

    $.each(filtered_list, printListItem); 
}
```

The problem is with the `key` and `target` variables. I'm not sure how to declare them such that they can be used in `value.key.search` and `$(target).empty();`. If I declare them as strings, it doesn't work. For example:

```
var array = [{'name': 'ben'}, {'name':'kit'}];
var query = $(this).val();
var key = "name";
var target = "div#recipes";
Search(array, key, query, target);
```

This doesn't really surprise me... but what I'm wondering is how I should go about abstracting the function, including the key and target values. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [bracket notation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

```
var filtered_list = $.grep(array, function (value, index) {
    return (value[key].search(search_string) !=-1);
}); //           ↑   ↑
```